# R function to create sum from rows, according to condition

Tags: r

I have got a list of drug doses from patient visits, here's an example:

```
patient <- c("patient1", "patient1", "patient1", "patient2", "patient2", "patient2", "patient2")
date <- c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2005, 2005, 2007, 2007)
drug <- c("paracetamol", "paracetamol", "paracetamol", "ibuprofen", "ibuprofen", "ibuprofen", "paracetamol")
dose <- c(1, 2, 2, 300, 400, 200, 2)
myinput <- data.frame(patient, date, drug, dose)

> myinput
   patient date        drug dose
1 patient1 2000 paracetamol    1
2 patient1 2000 paracetamol    2
3 patient1 2001 paracetamol    2
4 patient2 2005   ibuprofen  300
5 patient2 2005   ibuprofen  400
6 patient2 2007   ibuprofen  200
7 patient2 2007 paracetamol    2
```

Some of the rows contain info on the same drug that was taken on the same date and should be summed; e.g., `patient1` took a total `paracetamol` dose of `3` in `2000`. Doses on different  `dates`  should not be summed (nor should doses of different `drugs` ).

I was considering constructing a loop that extracts all rows in which `patient`, `date` and `drug` are identical and then uses `rowSums` to sum the doses. But I suspect that there must be a simpler function. Do you have a suggestion?

Desired output:

```
> myoutput
   patient date        drug dose
1 patient1 2000 paracetamol    3
2 patient1 2001 paracetamol    2
3 patient2 2005   ibuprofen  700
4 patient2 2007   ibuprofen  200
5 patient2 2007 paracetamol    2
```

Thanks!

Comment: In general the task you wish to perform is called summarisation by group. In base R, `aggregate` is used. But you will likely have an easy time of it , if you adopt `tidyverse` which gives almost trivial summarisation by nice verbs such as `group_by()` and `summarise()` : https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html?q=group#grouped-summaries-with-summarise